# put a var within string within array

Tags: php

I have an array, and I have this:

```
$title = "Envirometal Recycling : Scrap Metal Recyclers Caboolture - Scrap products Zinc";
```

I want to do this:

```
$title = "Envirometal Recycling : Scrap Metal Recyclers <?php echo $suburb[$rand_keys[0]] . "\n";?> - Scrap products Zinc";
```

Obviously the above is wrong, I aint sure how I should concantenate my code ( not sure if thats correct wording.

Comment: Take a look at the [string operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) and [`sprintf`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use curly brackets like so:

```
$title = "Envirometal Recycling : Scrap Metal Recyclers {$suburb[$rand_keys[0]]}\n - Scrap products Zinc";
```

Then you don't have to have odd concatenating situations revolving around quotes and double quotes.

ie, `$string = "John said, '" . $verbiage . "'";`

I think it looks pretty clean as `$string = "John said, '{$verbiage}'";`

Comment: the issue is, the code: <?php echo $suburb[$rand_keys[0]] . "\n";?> including the \n needs to be concantenated

Comment: Merely add the \n to the end of the string above. (Or wherever the break is supposed to reside). I updated my answer to reflect where you want your break.

Comment: thankyou , my issue has just dawned on me, I am trying to echo the var before its bloody declared. So will rejig my code.

Comment: That would definitely contribute to it not showing up properly. Best of luck.

Comment: Chose your answer because of your help, and you deserve points :)

Answer (score 3):

Concatenate is the correct word :)

To concatenate in PHP, use the period (`.`).

```
 $title = "Envirometal Recycling : Scrap Metal Recyclers".$suburb[$rand_keys[0]]. "\n- Scrap products Zinc";
```

Comment: What about the \n ( is that new line ? ) yep. So issue seems to be I am parsing this code before the array. So will need to rethink my code lol

Comment: Yes, `\n` when wrapped in double quotes is a newline. In this case, `$title` is a variable that equals a string concatenated with `$suburb[$rand_keys[0]]`'s value concatenated with the rest of the string, which has a newline in it. Make sense?

Answer (score 1):

maybe this is what u need?  hard to understand question

```
$title = "Envirometal Recycling : Scrap Metal Recyclers ". $suburb[$rand_keys[0]] . "- Scrap products Zinc";
```

then echo the whole thing

```
echo($title);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$title = "Envirometal Recycling : Scrap Metal Recyclers" . $suburb[$rand_keys[0]] . "- Scrap products Zinc";
```

Should do the trick